# Mathematica Kampé de Fériet Notation

Tags: power-series, hypergeometric-function, mathematica

I'm looking at the definition of the Kampé de Fériet function in Mathematica's Notation Reference Document (p.36 [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/PDF/Notations.pdf)), and there is one part of their notation that I'm not quite sure about.

In the attached formula, what does the highlighted 'q' refer to:
[Mathematica Notation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUlY8.png)

Thanks!